# Loading only certain rows from txt file into mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a .txt file that logs some information. I want to load it to MySQL table, but I have a following problem: the .txt log file isn't uniform, meaning it looks something like this:

```
04092012 16:07:34.988 stuff1 stuff2 username1 importantStuff
04092012 16:08:12.145 stuff1 stuff2 stuff3 username2 stuff4 importantStuff
```

Important thing to say is that all usernames begin with the same characters, just like here. I know that I'm supposed to use something like:

```
$lines=file(log.txt);

foreach($lines as $v) {
  $values = explode(' ',$v);
  ...
```

But I do not know how to transfer only date, time, username and importantStuff into MySQL table.

I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure none of the stuff parts contain the same pattern as the usernames?

Comment: Maybe an actual excerpt would be more helpful, a few different lines.

Comment: None of the stuff parts does not contain anything similar to the username. Usernames are nem1, nem2, nem3... up to nem350. Important thing is that not all lines contain username (and thus are not needed) and some lines in log.txt can contain up to 18 columns

Comment: The not knowing part is probably the biggest problem. However, it sounds like that you do not even have a clue how you add data at all to the database, right? I mean there is no code at all that shows *how* you actually add data to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents('log.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
foreach($lines as $v) {
   $values = explode(' ',$v);
   $all = count($values);
   $user = preg_match_all('/(user\w+\b)/', $v, $matches); // it will match all usernames that start with "user"
   $time = $values[1];
   $username = $matches[0][0];
   $stuff = $values[($all-1)];
   $date = $values[0];

   $query = "INSERT INTO `MyTable` ('".$date."', '".$time."', '".$username."', '".$stuff."')";
}
```

Comment: What about 'importantStuff' :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the stuff parts do not contain the same pattern as the username part you can use something like:

```
$lines=file(log.txt);

foreach($lines as $v) {
    $values = explode(' ',$v);
    $date = "";
    $time = "";
    $important = "";
    $username = "";
    foreach($values as $cnt => $val){
        if($cnt == 0){
            $date = $val;
        } else if($cnt == 1){
            $time = $val;
        } else if(substr($val, 0, 8) == 'username'){
            $username = $val;
        }
        $important = $val;
   }
   $query = "INSERT INTO logtable VALUES ('$date', $time', '$username', '$important')";
}
```

Comment: I love the `$important` here :)

Comment: Hehe, my solution could be improved, I like your solution better :)

Comment: +1 on `$important` just because I was going to say smth first about that variable not taking stuff out.